# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB not registered on local machine

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm having an issue with Visual Studio 2005. I'm writing an application in VB.net using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. I've got a couple of applications using that provider already and they all run fine. I can Publish them again or run them in the IDE and they work fine. When I try to run the new application I get the message that "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on local machine. I've started the application over several times with no change. Under Data Connections inside VS, I can open the database and see the tables, views and procedures. But it still gives me this message. I've tried to reinstall the driver and nothing changes. I've uninstalled in and reinstalled it, no change. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you recently changed the target platform (bitness - x86 / x64 / anycpu+prefer32bit Y/N) of your project?

Comment: No, I hadn't, but then I didn't set it either and it defaulted to any CPU. Once I changed it to x86 it ran fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access drivers are, as far as I know, bit-specific. If you have the 32 bit driver installed and your compile/run your app in x64 it will fail to find the driver. Match the bitness of your project to the bitness of your installed drivers (or cycle all the options). Remember that the Prefer32bit setting can influence the resulting bitness chosen in an AnyCPU situation (e.g. if you have 64bit drivers, and have AnyCPU+Prefer32=Y then you may encounter a fail)